# Invite logging DiscordJS v13 TypeError: Cannot read property 'inviter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

Code

```
const id = "815280236974964817"
client.on("ready", async () => {
    client.guilds.cache.get(id).invites.fetch().then(inv => {
        newInv = inv
    })
})
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member =>{
    if(member.guild.id !== id) return;
    member.guild.invites.fetch().then(gInvites =>{
        const invite = gInvites.find((inv) => newInv.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses)
        console.log(invite.inviter.tag)
    }) 
})
```

Error

```
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'inviter' of undefined
```

This worked fine in discord.js v12
I've the required intents enabled as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that `invite` is undefined.

The `find` function [returns undefined when it can't find an element in the array that matches your testing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

You need to handle this case by doing something like this:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member =>{
    if(member.guild.id !== id) return;
    member.guild.invites.fetch().then(gInvites =>{
        const invite = gInvites.find((inv) => newInv.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses)
        if (!invite) {
            // invite does not exist
            return;
        } else {
            // an invite matches the testing function
            console.log(invite.inviter.tag)
        }
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Everything returns invite does not exist 
;-;

Comment: @Azer154 are you expecting an invite to exist? What do you see if you `console.log` the `gInvites` variable.

Comment: Apparently invite's property isn't always assured...
And yes, I logged `gInvites` it logs all the invites of the guild.. Thanks for the help